# How do you highlight text surrounded by double equals

Tags: syntax-highlighting, highlight, filetype-markdown, plugin-vimwiki

I'm using vimwiki plugin with markdown. I'd like to highlight text using double equals, which isn't standard, but is quite useful. Ideally, this should replace background (for instance, yellow) and keep any other formatting, such as bold or italics.

```
Normal text. ==Highlighted text with **bold** and *italics*==. Normal text
```

Should be:

[image: Highlighted text with bold and italics]

Comment: The standard option is to define a syntax item for it (:help syntax, maybe?) and the `highlight def link` it to a group

Comment: what is the expected behavior when both bold and italic occurs like `*italic with **bold** inside*` « *italic with **bold** inside* » ? There is no `bolditalic` in Vim's highlight feature.

Comment: This is precisely one extra reason to try this "highlighting" solution: provided one text with italics inside, you can't simply surround it and make it bold, as it would lose visual formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same question. My solution is not perfect, since I do not do exactly what you want, but you can adapt my solution to yours, if you are willing to add more highlight groups.

To do close what you want, make the following `after/syntax/vimwiki.vim` file (I guess if you are just doing markdown, you could make it `after/syntax/markdown.vim`):

```
highlight MDHighlightH term=standout ctermfg=0 ctermbg=11 guifg=orangered guibg=yellow2
highlight MDHighlightHB term=standout ctermfg=0 ctermbg=11 guifg=orangered guibg=yellow2 cterm=bold

syntax region MDHighlight matchgroup=HighEnd start='==' end='==' concealends
highlight link MDHighlight MDHighlightH                                                                                                    

syntax region MDBoldHighlight matchgroup=HighEnd start='\*\*' end='\*\*' concealends containedin=MDHighlight contained
highlight link MDBoldHighlight MDHighlighHB
```

First, I make two new highlights. The first is identical to the `Todo` highlight. The second adds bold. (To see all the highlights that are currently available and their definitions, do `:highlight`. To see all the ones currently active, do `:so $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/hitest.vim`)

Next, I make the syntax groups. The first one  is for a highlight surrounded by `==`, and then it conceals the `==`. It is then linked to the first new highlight group that I made. The second is for bold that is contained within the highlight group. Again, the `**` are concealed, and it is linked to the second highlight group.

I did not do the italic one, but you can easily extend this for yourself.

However, I did not really like the result. The bold in the highlight does not actually make it stand out more. So instead, I went with this:

```
syntax region MDHighlight matchgroup=HighEnd start='==' end='==' concealends
highlight link MDHighlight Title

syntax region MDBoldHighlight matchgroup=HighEnd start='\*\*' end='\*\*' concealends containedin=MDHighlight contained
highlight link MDBoldHighlight Todo
```

The `Title` highlight group basically makes it yellow (for me). And then the `Todo` makes it like a highlight. So the "first level" of highlighting for me just changes the font color, and then the bold highlights it. I think this is better because the bold highlight actually stands out more.

This biggest drawback is that if you have any other vimwiki syntax within your highlight, it will break the conceal of that. For instance, if you highlight a vimwiki link, it won't conceal it (where it shows only the title when your cursor is on another line), and the link color won't work. It will only keep the highlight syntax that you define. This is because it is in the `after` folder in vimwiki. (Putting it in `syntax/vimwiki.vim` also breaks the link conceal.) I started to look through vimwiki to see how the link conceal works so that I could add it to my file, but it is very complicated, so I abandoned it. The links still work---if you hit `Enter` on the link, you still go to that file. It is only the conceal that does not work.